# Removing items in list, python style and c++ style

Tags: c++, python

I've been working on learning python and somehow came up with following codes:

```
for item in list:
    while list.count(item)!=1:
        list.remove(item)
```

I was wondering if this kind of coding can be done in c++. (Using list length for the for loop while decreasing its size) If not, can anyone tell me why?

Thanks!

Comment: Actually you can't even do that in Python. You're silently skipping items, and with other collections you'll get an exception.

Comment: you should probably iterate over `lis[:]`.

Comment: Horrible, horrible HORRIBLE idea to delete items from a list as you're iterating over it. makeitstopmakeitstopmakeitstop

Comment: Use two lists which is what @AshwiniChaudhary suggests with a copy.

Comment: Better use `set()` here, `lis=set(lis)`.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary With the caveat that it'll change the ordering, of course.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary -- Assuming the elements are hashable and that order doesn't matter.

Comment: @mgilson well in that case, `unique_everseen` recipe from itertools is a good option.

Comment: There's also std::set in C++, which also reorders elements.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary -- Except that requires that the item be hashable (or at least that the `key` function returns something that is hashable).  But it's a good recipe (that I hadn't thought of before)  Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: What is this doing? Is it removing adjacent duplicates from the list? If that's all it is in C++ you just call `myList.unique();`

Comment: @Dave: it removes all dupes (not just adjacent ones), keeping the last, and maintains the original order of the list.

Comment: so will this code generate errors like missing certain items or have a memory problem??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am not a big Python programmer, but it seems like the above code removes duplicates from a list. Here is a C++ equivalent:

```
list.sort();
list.unique();
```

As for modifying the list while iterating over it, you can do that as well. Here is an example:

```
for (auto it = list.begin(), eit = list.end(); it != eit; ) {
    if (std::count(it, eit, *it) > 1)
        it = list.erase(it);
    else
        ++it;
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: removes _consecutive_ duplicates*. `unique` won't remove all duplicates, just consecutive ones

Comment: @VladLazarenko I don't know python, is a `list` a sorted container in it? If not, your original code probably matched the python better.

Comment: Python's `list` is not sorted. Also note that it's more similar to a `std::vector` than to `std::list` (dynamic, over-allocating array rather than linked list).

Comment: @delnan: like vector, really? So removing the front element shifts all of the consecutive elements in memory? I am in no position to argue, but it sounds like a bad choice to implement a general purpose list for a platform like Python IDK...

Comment: Yes, really. And yes, that makes it a bad choice when you're mainly removing from the front. But it's really fast at many other sequence operations, it's as compact as it gets, so for most use cases it beats the alternatives. Plus, it's not the only sequence in the standard library (there's `queue` and `deque` for when you want that rather than a dynamic array). Did you know that C++ gurus also advocate `std::vector` as the default sequence container?

Comment: @delnan: Cannot agree more. I even have a special post about removing elements from a vector, [here](http://lazarenko.me/2013/01/14/erasing-vector-the-smart-way/). Anyhow, that's nice to know! Thanks for the insight!

Comment: @delnan If it's a `std::vector` there's still a simple C++ want to do it. See my answer

Comment: @SteveJessop: No, for list only the iterators and references to the erased element is invalidated [§23.2.2.3/3]. For vector, you are right.

Comment: @Vlad: you're right of course. I was mentally translating python `list` to C++ `vector`, missed that you're using C++ `list`.

Answer (score 0):

In C++, you can compose something like this from various algorithms of the standard library, check out remove(), find(), However, the way your algorithm is written, it looks like O(n^2) complexity. Sorting the list and then scanning over it to put one of each value into a new list has O(n log n) complexity, but ruins the order.

In general, both for Python and C++, it is often better to copy or move elements to a temporary container and then swap with the original than modifying the original in-place. This is easier to get right since you don't step on your own feet (see delnan's comment) and it is faster because it avoids repeated reallocation and copying of objects.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I'd do it.

```
//If we will not delete an element of the list
for (std::list<MyType>::iterator it = MyList.begin(); it != MyList.end();++it)
{
   //my operation here
}

//If we will delete an element of the list
for (std::list<MyType>::iterator it = MyList.begin(); it != MyList.end();)
{
std::list<MyType>::iterator itt = it;
++itt;
MyList.erase(it);
it = itt;
}
```

You can use the size of the list, but it is not comparable to [it] because [it].

Certain features of std:: data classes are enabled or disabled as a design decision. Sure, you can make your own function MyList[int i], but it will lead to a large speed gimp due to the nature of lists.

Answer (score 0):

In C++ you can in some conditions remove elements from a container while iterating over it.  This depends on the container and on the operation you want to do.

Currently there are different interpretations of your code snipplet in the different answers.  My interpretation is, that you want to delete all the elements which exists more than once in the list.

Here is the solution in C++: it first counts the elements in another container (std::map) and removes the appropriate elements from the list afterwards.

```
#include <list>
#include <map>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

int main() {

  std::list<int> li { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 2, 2 };

  // Create count map: element -> count 
  std::map<int, int> cm;
  std::for_each( li.begin(), li.end(), [&cm](int i) { ++cm[i]; } );

  // Remove all elements from list with count > 1
  std::for_each( cm.begin(), cm.end(), 
         [&li](std::pair<const int, int> const p) { 
       if( p.second > 1) {
         li.remove( p.first );
       }
    } );

  // Output all elements from remaining list
  std::for_each( li.begin(), li.end(), 
         [](int i) { std::cout << i << std::endl; } );

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: This might be faster than spamming `std::count`, but I think that code was only there to show that you can modify a list while iterating over it. There's no way this is faster than `sort` and `unique`... I would think...

Comment: I started writing this, when there was another solution from Vlad - I'll remove the remark about performance.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know Python but someone said in a comment that a list is equivalent to a C++ vector and it is not sorted, so here goes....

```
std::vector<int> v{1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 2, 2, 1};

v.erase(std::unique(v.begin(), v.end()), v.end());
```

`v` contains `{1, 2, 3, 2, 1}` after this code. If the goal is to remove all duplicates (not just consecutive duplicates) you'll have to sort the vector first: `std::sort(v.begin(), v.end());`

Answer (score 0):

`std::vector` is the container in C++ that is most similar to Python's `list`, and here's the correct way to modify a vector while iterating it:

```
template <typename T>
void dedupe(std::vector<T> &vec) {
    for (std::vector<T>::iterator it = vec.begin(); it != vec.end(); ) {
        if (std::count(vev.begin(), vec.end(), *it) != 1) {
            it = vec.erase(it);
        } else {
            ++it;
        }
    }
}
```

It's not necessarily the most efficient way to dedupe, but it works.

> Using list length for the for loop while decreasing its size

If you insist on using the length rather than the `end()`, then you can use an index instead of an iterator:

```
template <typename T>
void dedupe(std::vector<T> &vec) {
    for (std::vector<T>::size_type pos = 0; pos != vec.size(); ) {
        if (std::count(vec.begin(), vec.end(), vec[pos]) != 1) {
            vec.erase(vec.begin() + pos);
        } else {
            ++pos;
        }
    }
}
```

I'm assuming that the intention of your Python code is to remove all duplicates, by the way, and that the fact it doesn't is a bug. For example input `[2,2,1,3,3,1,2,3]`, output `[1,1,2,3]`. If what you said is what you meant, then a direct translation of your code to C++ is:

```
template <typename T>
void dedupe(std::vector<T> &vec) {
    for (std::vector<T>::size_type pos = 0; pos < vec.size(); ++pos) {
        T item = vec[pos];
        while (std::count(vec.begin(), vec.end(), item) != 1) {
            vec.erase(std::find(vec.begin(), vec.end(), item));
        }
    }
}
```